# json_encode returns NULL when trying to echo to AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm getting a JSON formatted response from a web API. When I try to json_encode the response and echo it to AJAX, it gives me a null response on the AJAX side.

PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$theurl);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);   

    if(is_callable('curl_init')){
       echo "Enabled<br/>";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "Not enabled";
    }

    // Send the request & save response to $resp

    GLOBAL $resp;

    $resp = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($resp);
//displays: string(221) "{"year": 2011, "type": "movie", "format": "BluRay",     "releaseGroup": "BKZ", "title": "A Dangerous Method", "screenSize": "480p", "videoCodec": "XviD", "mimetype": "video/x-msvideo", "container": "avi", "audioCodec": "AC3"}" "{\"year\": 2011, \"type\": \"movie\", \"format\": \"BluRay\", \"releaseGroup\": \"BKZ\", \"title\": \"A Dangerous Method\", \"screenSize\": \"480p\", \"videoCodec\": \"XviD\", \"mimetype\": \"video\/x-msvideo\", \"container\": \"avi\", \"audioCodec\": \"AC3\"}"

echo json_encode($resp);
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
            url : 'includes/file_uploader.php', // requesting a PHP script
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function (data) { // data contains the PHP script output

               alert(data);

               console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);

               console.log(data);
            }
        })
```

The var_dump before the echo shows all the right stuff. Why do I keep getting null on the AJAX side?

Comment: I uploaded the AJAX too.

Comment: your response is invalid string

Comment: your `echo "Enabled<br/>";`/`echo "Not enabled";` will make your returned `data` invalid json, which could cause your `$.ajax()` to error to `null`

Comment: How should I echo it as an array?

Comment: just echo the $resp if it is already json

Comment: I did, but someone here mentioned it's an invalid string?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure the only thing your script is returning back is a formatted JSON string, since you're telling javascript that's the type of response you're expecting.  In your php script you have several debug pieces of information that are causing your response to not be JUST a json string.  Additionally if you're already retrieving a json_encoded string from the server you are making a curl call to, you don't want to re-encode this string as it's already formatted.

What you likely want to do is:

Get rid of this code block:

```
if(is_callable('curl_init')){
echo "Enabled<br/>";
}
else
{
   echo "Not enabled";
}
```

curl_init should always be callable since it's a base php function.  Then remove your var_dump and the json encoding of the $resp variable and then print out the response.  Your final script can probably be boiled down to something like:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$theurl);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);   

echo curl_exec($ch);
```

Ultimately you probably should add some better handling to the results from curl_exec in case the call fails, but hopefully this will get you on the right track

Comment: Good help and I'm getting closer. I tried your code, and it's not sending any text to ajax and returns empty. The alert on success in ajax shows [object Object] while the print function prints out the api response perfectly before the echo.

Comment: Check the HTTP headers in either Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools to see what is actually being returned to the browser